# Windows cannot initialize a synchronization event

Tags: windows-xp, defragment

I get the above error message in a Windows batch file that tries to defrag two disks (Windows XP Professional SP3), on the second defrag. The first one works fine. The relevant code is:

```
echo My C: defrag started: %date% %time% > %logfile%
defrag C: /v 1>> %logfile% 2>&1
echo My C: defrag finished: %date% %time% >> %logfile%
echo My E: defrag started: %date% %time% >> %logfile%
defrag E: /v 1>> %logfile% 2>&1
echo My E: defrag finished: %date% %time% >> %logfile%
```

Google shows nothing helpful. Any ideas what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: These suggestions are unlikely to help, but I was unable to find any useful information from Microsoft on this one.

[1] Try defragging drive C last.

[2] Check to see if you have Offline Files enabled.  In the Windows Explorer menu, choose Tools, Folder Options.  On the Offline Files tab, if they are enabled, try disabling them.  If you need offline files, I guess this is not really a solution, but frankly the Windows Offline Files feature is a disaster anyway and I wouldn't trust it with a readme file.

Comment: I tried both of these at the same time and now it works. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome. Now I'm wondering which one fixed the problem. <grin>